# Start windows service automatically when system reboots

Tags: service, windows-services

I have installed a windows service in a server with automatic mode.But when system reboots its not starting automatically.It is still in start state only. Manually i am starting the service. Please suggest me how can the service get started when system reboots.Service is working fine.No dependencies.

Comment: If it's set to start automatically and it's not running when you check, I'd suggest that perhaps you're missing a dependency and it's starting to early, then failing to start... so it *appears* to not have started when you check

Comment: Also, try Automatic (Delayed Start) on the more recent OS's.

Comment: no when i started manually its starting properly.When the system shutdowns or reboots its not starting automatically.

Comment: Is this a serive you work yourself? if not you may get a better answer on serverfault.se

Answer (score 1):

Check the system logs (run compmgmt.msc , under "Performance Logs and Alerts"), for any error messages. It seems like you service is not starting for a good reason, most likely a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for my problem.By setting property of service to local system its working fine.

Comment: I have set sshd to Local System and Automatic but it still doesn't start on boot.

Answer (score -2):

Go to start
type services.msc and press enter.

On the services list that opens up, right click on the service and select Properties. The dialog that opens has an option 'Automatic' for starting your service.

Comment: it is in automatic option only

Answer (score -3):

Just set the preference to Automatic and the service would automatically run

Comment: The questioner explicitly states the Windows is set to automatic already. Something else will probably be wrong instead...